# Optional non-scrolling header in a fixed-height element

Tags: css

I have a fixed-size box that is set to scroll when it overflows. However, sometimes it has a header, and sometimes it doesn't; and I can't figure out a way to style it to look well when the header appears. I know exactly why it happens (the header pushes the 100%-height scrolling element down and out of its container), but I can't figure out a non-table way to fix it. [Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U8rPj/) showing the problem; and the full code for SO archives:

HTML:

```
<div class="fixed-size">
  <ul class="scrollable">
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>four</li>
    <li>five</li>
    <li>six</li>
    <li>seven</li>
    <li>eight</li>
    <li>nine</li>
    <li>ten</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="fixed-size">
  <div class="stays-at-top">
      Header
  </div>
  <ul class="scrollable">
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>four</li>
    <li>five</li>
    <li>six</li>
    <li>seven</li>
    <li>eight</li>
    <li>nine</li>
    <li>ten</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fixed-size {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #fcc;
}

.scrollable {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.stays-at-top {
    background-color: #f99;
}​
```

If it's not clear, I want the header (`.stays-at-top`) to stay at the top (i.e. not scroll with his friends).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/EyPQW/6/

```
.fixed-size {
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #fcc;
}
.scrollable {
    height: 100px;  
    overflow: auto;    
}
.stays-at-top + .scrollable {
    margin-top: 17px;
    height: 83px;     
}
.stays-at-top {
    background-color: #f99;
    position: fixed;
    width: 200px;
}​
```

This should meet the full requirements.

`.fixed-size` specifies a `width`, but not a `height`.

`.scrollable` specifies a `height` and `overflow: auto` to allow its contents to scroll.

`.stays-at-top + .scrollable` matches when we have a `.stays-at-top` and a `.scrollable` element immediately adjacent to each other, i.e. when we have a fixed header. Here we add a `margin-top` to enable the first item to clear the fixed header, and reset the `height` value to the value specified in `.scrollable` minus the `margin-top` value.

`.stays-at-top` requires `position: fixed` and a `width` matching the `width` in `.fixed-size`.

Comment: The headerless case now looks wrong; and the scrollbar goes over the header (which is somewhat unintuitive, from the usability viewpoint). The first can be fixed by applying different classes to `.scrollable` depending on whether header was there or not (or use adjacency selector); but it's still not quite what I am looking for. I know it's a non-trivial problem, that's why I posted it :(

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. This comes closest to what I want so far, so I'll accept it unless a CSS guru happens by.

Comment: All right! Having to manually calculate heights is inelegant, but it does exactly what I want from the users' point of view. Thanks!

Comment: The only way of avoiding manual calculation of the heights would be to use server side code, or a CSS pre-processor like Sass

Comment: The problem with both this and the SASS, and the reason I said it's inelegant, is that you have to decide on the `font-size`. If the user agent overrides the font settings (for example, for visually impaired), the calculation is thrown off. So if you're at any point using `17px` as an assumption, it can break (whether you use serverside, SASS or hardcoded CSS). You could do it with JS and dynamically inspect font size and calculate, but that'd be horrible. Still, as I said, closest so far to what I want; and it may be that there isn't yet an answer that would fully satisfy me in current CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Just move the `scrollable` class to the parent and remove the `height:100%`, `width:100%`, and change the `overflow-y:auto` to simply `overflow:auto`.

As such: http://jsfiddle.net/jglovier/U8rPj/4/

Comment: Well you didn't say anything in your question about that, but I'm assuming what you mean is you want it to remain in view while the content scrolls below it?

Comment: ...simply add `position: fixed;`, `top: 0px` and specify the relevant width as so: http://jsfiddle.net/jglovier/U8rPj/3/

Comment: Sorry :( This again doesn't do what I need. In this version, the first row disappears under the header. And the scroll area is not one row shorter. As for me not saying it in the question, I would have thought the class name `.stays-at-top` is quite descriptive enough, as is the fact that I conspicuously left it out of `.scrollable`. But I'll edit the question just in case.

Comment: Technically `.stays-at-top` could simply refer to the item staying at the top of the content, not that it "remains visible". Here's a version that resolves the issue with my last attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/jglovier/U8rPj/4/